# Property of the limit of function proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

If $c≠0$ and $\lim_{x→c}⁡〖f(x)〗=L$, prove that $\lim_{x→1/c}⁡〖f(1/x)〗=L$

I know that meaning for all $ε>0$, there exist a $δ>0$ such that $0<|x-c|<δ$  implies $|f(x)-L|<ε$. How can I use these to prove the conclusion.

Comment: Consider $|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{c}|$. How close should $1/x$ be to $1/c$ to imply that $|x - c|  < \delta$? Once you show this, then the original statement about the continuity of $f(x)$ can be used.

Comment: Are you given-assuming $\;f\;$ is continuous at $\;c\;$ ? I ask because of your question's title.

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes, since $limx→c〖f(x)〗=L$ exists, so the left limite and the right limit should be the same, so it should be continuous at c

Comment: Not at all, @Diana. It still would have to be that $\;f(c)=L\;$ and that may or may not be true.

Comment: I see your point, I change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say |x-c| < $\delta$ you mean $\delta$ - c < x < $\delta$ + c.  Now restate that inequality in terms of 1/x.  Can you work from there to construct a new $\delta_{1/x}$ which works for your limit?

Comment: yes, I cna construct a new $δ_{1/x}=min{{1/(c+δ)}-(1/c),{1/(c-δ)}-(1/c)}$, just plug back and I got $|(1/x)-(1/c)|<δ_{1/x}$ and I'm done, Am I correct?

Comment: but this only show that $1/c$ is a cluster point, not $|f(1/x)−L|<ε$. I need both of them to be true, prove this property.

Comment: I got it, thanks